# In python, what is niter, how is it different to counter?

Tags: python

I am looking at a simple bit of code:

```
def ismandelbrot(c):
    z=c
    for niter in range(1000):
        z = z*z + c
        if abs(z) > 1000:
            return False
    return True
```

I don't know what niter is, how is it different to saying `for i in range(1000)` and where can you look up what different functions do?

Comment: It's not a function, it's just the loop variable

Comment: Consider `i` as the exact samething as `niter` in this case and you will be fine.

Comment: And if you are not going to use the variable in your loop it is more pythonic to use `_`

Comment: To answer your question precisely: `niter` is a name. It is different from `counter` because counter is a different name. It is completely up to you what names to use. You could write `for FOOGLESNIZZ in range(1000):` and then refer to that name, or don't refer to that name.

Comment: A common idiom is to use: `for _ in iterable:` when you don't use the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`niter` is the variable name you are using for your loop. If you change it to `i`, it will result in the very same behavior you are experiencing, since you do not use the loop variable inside the loop. If you were using `niter` inside the loop, then changing it to `i` in the `for` row would give you the task of changing all its occurrences inside the loop. The loop variable changes its value in each iteration of the loop.